# ORACLE, XMLAGG(arg), null arg

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I Have a query:

```
SELECT  xmlelement("Response",
            xmlelement("hist",
              xmlelement("details",
                xmlagg(x.node)))
          ) AS XML_HIST,
          x.cnt
 FROM     (
            SELECT  null AS node,
                    COUNT(1) OVER() AS cnt
            FROM    dual
            --WHERE 1=2
         ) x
  GROUP BY x.cnt
```

Query x was made as it is for this question (sensitive data).

When query x return any data, everything's fine. But when there is no records in table (here: WHERE 1=2), my code in package fails with error no_data_found.

i'm trying to find soultion diffrent than

```
<<inner_block>>
begin
SELECT..
exception
when others then...
end inner_block;
```

i tried to do something like

```
SELECT  MAX(xmlelement("docGetPackageHistoryResponse",
            xmlelement("histories",
              xmlelement("contract-history",
                xmlagg(x.node)))
          )) AS XML_HIST,
    MAX(cnt)
```

but I get an error ORA-22950: cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method.

Any ideas?
Thanks :)

PS please, don't ask me questions like "why you tring avoid inner block solution?".

Answer (score 1):

The error is from applying the aggregate `max()` to the XMLElement, which doesn't really make sense; and without that it behaves the same as your original query anyway.

I think you're just aggregating at the wrong point; you can do this:

```
SELECT xmlelement("Response",
         xmlelement("hist",
           xmlelement("details",
             (
               SELECT xmlagg(x.node)
               FROM (
                 SELECT null AS node,
                        COUNT(1) OVER() AS cnt
                 FROM   dual
                 WHERE 1=2
               ) x
               GROUP BY x.cnt
             )
           )
         )
       ) AS XML_HIST
FROM dual
/

XML_HIST                                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Response><hist><details></details></hist></Response>
```

You can't see the inner count as a seperate column in the result set, but it doesn't look like you really need it.